# Missing Python packages on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, python, dependencies

For a weeek I've been trying to install a piece of software on a fresh install of CentOS 8. The installation process and the software itself work fine on CentOS 7 but I was tasked with installing it on CentOS 8.

The main problem right now is that some python packages are missing. Specifically I can't get the following package names:

```
MySQL-python
libxml2-python
numpy
python-imaging
python2-pyside
python-netifaces
```

I can of course install the libraries via pip2 but it doesn't seem to satisfy the dependencies.

Will we have to update the dependencies and maybe change some code or is there a way for me to get it working as is? Preferrably with EPEL 8 but I get the same errors with EPEL 7 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 8 is based on RHEL 8, which switched to Python 3 as the default. Many Python 2 packages are no longer available, or have changed names — for example, NumPy for Python 2 is `python2-numpy`.

From a purely Pythonic perspective, the best approach in your situation is to use a virtual environment: install the CentOS `python2-virtualenv` package, then run

```
python2 -m virtualenv --system-site-packages yourenv
```

(replacing `yourenv` with the name you want to give your virtual environment, which will also be the directory it’s created in), and activate the environment with

```
source yourenv/bin/activate
```

You can then install your Python dependencies using `pip install` without affecting the system outside the virtual environment.

However I get the impression you’re using a package, with dependencies on RPM packages. That will be harder to fix, and the best approach will depend on other factors. If the packaged software is available for Python 3, I would look into packaging that instead; otherwise, you could try to rework the existing package, but there’s a decent chance that will be more complicate than using a virtual environment...

See [Python in RHEL 8](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/14/python-in-rhel-8/) for details.

Comment: Yes, our package depends on RPM packages. I have found python3 variants or currently maintained forks for all packages but pyside. There doesn't seem to be a pyside (or pyside2) RPM package for CentOS 8 at this time.